# About Garman's inventory model

Tags: poisson-process

In Garman's inventory model (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304405X76900064), buying order and selling order are Poisson processes with order size = 1. Buying price and selling price are denoted by pb and ps, that is, the market maker gets pb when she sells a stock to the others, and spends ps to buy a stock from the others.

Garman then calculates the probability of the inventory of the market maker, says Q(k, t+dt) = probability to get 1 dollar x Q(k-1, t) + probability to lose 1 dollar x Q(k+1, t) + no buying or selling order x Q(k, t), where Q(k, t+dt) = probability to have k money at time t+dt.

In the above equation, I think Garman had split the money received and loss by buying or selling a shock in many sub-Poisson process, otherwise, getting 1 dollar or losing 1 dollar are impossible, as market maker receive pb dollar and loses ps dollar in each order, but not 1 dollar.

Is my statement correct?

Thank you very much.